# Is "I'm afraid" natural to use in this situation?

Tags: usage, idiomatic-language

Your father wants you to be a doctor.

> To disagree I said: **I'm afraid** I can't be a doctor. It is a very difficult job.

My question is: Is it convenient to use "I'm afraid" in such context?

If no why not?

I want to know the real use of "I'm afraid (that)"

Comment: It's fine. You just expressed your doubt about being able to become a doctor befauce of some difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "convenient", but your usage is not incorrect.

You may be expressing a *concern* about becoming a doctor, possibly due to all the years of studying, which you do not want to struggle against.

Without further context it is not easy to know what your "*fear*" might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were understood.

> used to express polite or formal apology or regret. "I'm afraid I
>   don't understand" synonyms:   sorry, sad, distressed, regretful,
>   apologetic "I'm afraid that your daughter is ill"

Google Dictionary

However, I'm afraid you used it incorrectly. In answer to your father, you are probably not apologetic about not wanting to be a doctor.

"I don't wish to be a doctor as I am not interested in medicine."

"I don't have the time or inclination to study that hard."

You might literally be afraid that you won't measure up -- that you are not smart enough to be a doctor.